# logstash - convert hex to ascii

Tags: plugins, logstash

I wonder if there is any alternative to [this hex plugin](https://libraries.io/rubygems/logstash-filter-hex). 
It's actually a nice and simple plugin but the problem is the latest updates for this plugin dated back to
2016.

My second question is how to update logstash on Linux while retaining custom plugins such as logstash-filter-hex? Last time the plugin was removed after the package update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin stopped working, you can replicate the functionality of this plugin using a `ruby` filter in your logstash pipeline.

For example, consider the two log lines:

```
{ "exampleString": "convert string to hex", "exampleInt": 10 }
{ "hexString": "636f6e766572742068657820746f20737472696e67", "hexInt": "a" }
```

To convert the fields `exampleString` and `exampleInt` to HEX and the fields `hexString` and `hexInt` from HEX to ascii, you can use the following config in logstash.

```
filter {
    if [exampleString] and [exampleInt] {
        ruby {
            code => "event.set('[toHexString]', event.get('[exampleString]').unpack('H*').first)"
        }
        ruby {
            code => "event.set('[toHexINT]', event.get('[exampleInt]').to_i.to_s(16))"
        }
    }
    if [hexString] and [hexInt] {
        ruby {
            code => "event.set('[fromHexString]', [event.get('[hexString]')].pack('H*'))"
        }
        ruby {
            code => "event.set('[fromHexINT]', event.get('[hexInt]').to_i(16).to_s)"
        }
    }
}
```

And your result will be something like this.

```
{
    "fromHexString" => "convert hex to string",
       "fromHexINT" => "10",
       "@timestamp" => 2020-05-18T12:41:37.624Z,
         "@version" => "1",
        "hexString" => "636f6e766572742068657820746f20737472696e67",
           "hexInt" => "a",
             "host" => "elk"
}
{
         "toHexINT" => "a",
       "@timestamp" => 2020-05-18T12:41:37.622Z,
         "@version" => "1",
    "exampleString" => "convert string to hex",
      "toHexString" => "636f6e7665727420737472696e6720746f20686578",
       "exampleInt" => 10,
             "host" => "elk"
}
```

Where you can see that the fields were converted from hex and to hex.

Regarding your second question, when you update logstash it will update the files that references your installed plugins, so if you have a non bundled plugin, you will need to install it again.